# Error in basic CRUD app when trying to update: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: addresses.player_id)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple CRUD app with Rails. So far I'm up to the CRUD for `Players`. Soon I'll have `HighSchoolTeams`, `ClubTeams` and `Addresses`.

I'm running into an issue when I try to update an existing player. I get the following error:

```
Started PATCH "/players/3" for ::1 at 2019-12-13 13:43:53 -0800
Processing by PlayersController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"2fyMlnOWCTn5pt8pyf/W86fRjCO4Af85sbl+3RFDg2OIXAU+T2wU7VxEU3gAxOZPNXvYDcjYpNXMWhImJiEkDQ==", "player"=>{"first_name"=>"Ben", "middle_name"=>"Patrick", "last_name"=>"Stein", "height"=>"", "weight"=>"", "birthday"=>"", "high_school_team"=>"", "club_team"=>"", "email"=>"", "phone_number"=>"", "address_line_one"=>"", "address_line_two"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", "zip"=>"", "notes"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Player", "id"=>"3"}
  Player Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:30:in `update'
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:32:in `update'
  Address Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."player_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["player_id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:32:in `update'
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/players_controller.rb:32:in `update'
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Allocations: 5907)

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: addresses.player_id):

app/controllers/players_controller.rb:32:in `update'
```

I'm not sure what is going on with the error. There is indeed no `addresses.player_id` column. I didn't intend for there to be. What I intend is for players to reference an `Address` by having an `address_id` column.

In looking over my code, I don't see anything problematic. The payload is successfully reaching the server, and the player is successfully being loaded. The problem is with `@player.update`.

**players_controller.rb**

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def edit
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])

    if @player.update(player_params)
      redirect_to @player
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  private
    def player_params
      params_for_player = params
        .require(:player)
        .permit(:first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :height, :weight, :birthday, :high_school_team, :club_team, :email, :phone_number, :address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :state, :zip, :notes)
        .except(:address_line_one, :address_line_two, :city, :state, :zip)
      params_for_player["address"] = nil
      params_for_player["high_school_team"] = nil
      params_for_player["club_team"] = nil

      return params_for_player
    end
end
```

**player.rb**

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :address
  belongs_to :high_school_team, optional: true
  belongs_to :club_team, optional: true
end
```

**address.rb**

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
end
```

**schema.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_12_12_025909) do

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "line_one"
    t.string "line_two"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "club_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "high_school_teams", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "players", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "middle_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.decimal "height"
    t.decimal "weight"
    t.date "birthday"
    t.integer "high_school_team_id"
    t.integer "club_team_id"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.integer "address_id"
    t.text "notes"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["address_id"], name: "index_players_on_address_id"
    t.index ["club_team_id"], name: "index_players_on_club_team_id"
    t.index ["high_school_team_id"], name: "index_players_on_high_school_team_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "players", "addresses"
  add_foreign_key "players", "club_teams"
  add_foreign_key "players", "high_school_teams"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I intend is for players to reference an Address by having an address_id column.

```
class Player
  belongs_to :address
end

class Address
  has_one :player
end
```

`belongs_to` goes on the model with the foreign key. But I would say that its not very logical. `addresses` should have a `player_id` and `belong_to :player`. Its the players address and not vice versa.

> If you want to set up a one-to-one relationship between two models,
>   you'll need to add belongs_to to one, and has_one to the other. How do
>   you know which is which?
>
> The distinction is in where you place the foreign key (it goes on the
>   table for the class declaring the belongs_to association), but you
>   should give some thought to the actual meaning of the data as well.
>   The has_one relationship says that one of something is yours - that
>   is, that something points back to you. For example, it makes more
>   sense to say that a supplier owns an account than that an account owns
>   a supplier.
>   - [Rails Guides: Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one)

Comment: I was thinking that an `Address` doesn't really belong to a `Player`. What if two players live at the same address?

Comment: You're overthinking it. You don't need to normalize the addresses table.

Comment: Each player has one address. On the rare occasion you have two users with the exact same address then you get a slight bit of duplication but thats not a real issue.

Comment: If two players point to a single address, that won't cause a bug? With a `has_one` association, I would think there would be a bug if it "has two".

Comment: Thats why you have the player_id on the addresses table. Its impossible for two users to have the same address.

Comment: I don't think we really have to debate this. This exact case has been done to death, and not in your way.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand how it works, not question it. I'm pretty new to Rails and with dealing with database stuff. With `player_id` on the addresses table, I don't see how it would work when two players live in the same house. You'd want two different `player_ids` for that address.

Comment: No you have got it backwards. Each player would have its own row on addresses table. Each row has its own player_id. Thus an address can only ever have one player.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204241/discussion-between-adam-zerner-and-max).